# Премудрости объявление указателя в c++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, недавно начал изучения c++ и остановился на указателях. Читал про них на разных источниках и везде объявление указателя выглядит по-разному. Не могли бы вы ответить, чем различаются следующие объявление указателей:

```
int *ptr1;
int* ptr2;
int * prt3;
```

Answer (score 4):

Как сказали выше (или ниже) - ничем не отличаются. Но есть все таки одно отличие - это стилистика.

Большинство программистов делится на две группы - те, кто ставит звездочку к типу или те, кто ставит к переменной (и у каждой группы есть свои аргументы за и против).

И есть ещё две группки, маленькие - первая ставит звездочку посредине (это не определившиеся) и те, кто задает подобные вопросы на форумах (@Default, к примеру), приправив их различной легендой (как лучше, как правильней, в чем разница).

В целом, лучше узнать кодстайл в компании или выработать свой и будет счастье.

P.S.

А лучше использовать `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` и вопроса о звездочке может долго не возникать.

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно ничем.

Как и

```
int*p;
int    *    p;
```

Наличие пробелов **ни на что не влияет**.

Просто кому как удобнее и привычнее.

И сразу - учтите, что в

```
int* p, n;
```

`p` будет указателем на `int`, но `n` - просто `int`.